# Express w/ Mongoose: Can't increment beyond 5 or so increments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Essential functionality here is 1 click = 1 vote, it updates a vote parameter in MongoDB and it is incrementing within MongoDB just fine. However after about 5 votes it stops incrementing. When I refresh the browser it allows me 5 more increments then no more until the next refresh..

Is there something I'm missing, perhaps pertaining to the 'findOneAndUpdate' method? I've tried just using the 'update' method and the behavior is the same. I've checked the docs and found no mention of a '$inc' increment/time/interval limit. Here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/food');


//Allow all requests from all domains & localhost
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


var usersSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  vote: Number
});

var bkyes = mongoose.model('bkyes', usersSchema);

app.get('/bkyes', function(req, res) {
bkyes.find({}, function(err, bkyes) {
  res.send(bkyes);
  });
});

app.post('/bkyes', function(req, res, next) {
  bkyes.findOneAndUpdate({$inc: { vote: 1 }})
      .exec(function(err, foundObject) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: why use `findOneAndUpdate`? You're not passing in a query.  why not just [#update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)

Comment: What method would you suggest for not passing in a query but just incrementing a value in the db? This is sort of what I've accomplished with  'findOneAndUpdate', let me know if there is a better way. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the last few words of your comment, I will look at `Update` now instead of `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: `update` has the same issue. When I refresh the browser it allows me 5 more increments then no more until the next refresh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New dev and I didn't know you have to send back a status or else the browser will just build up pending requests. Ignorance I know but hopefully this helps someone. Modified POST request code:

```
app.post('/bkyes', function(req, res, next) {
  bkyes.update({$inc: { vote: 1 }})
      .exec(function(err, foundObject) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }});
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment value of vote then just use findAndModify.here my query its work perfectly fine and it increment vote value

```
db.getCollection('bikes').findAndModify({update:{$inc:{vote:1}}})
```